# Can someone correct errors? - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Can someone correct errors in code? "updater" is a window that opens when you turn the main program. I am new to Visual Basic so I ask You for help. Updater is for advertising. I'm shooting an ad my program on YT. Sorry for my english and syntax, but I come from Poland. Thanks.

```
Public Class updater

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PerplexButton1.Click
        PerplexProgressBar1.Value = PerplexProgressBar1.Minimum
        PerplexButton1.Visible = False
        PerplexProgressBar1.Visible = True
        PerplexLabel2.Visible = True
        PerplexLabel3.Visible = True

        Timer1.Start()

        PerplexLabel3.Text = "Connecting to server."
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        PerplexProgressBar1.Increment(1)

        If PerplexProgressBar1.Value = 10 Then
            PerplexLabel3.Text = "Connecting to server.."

        End If

        If PerplexProgressBar1.Value = 20 Then
            PerplexLabel3.Text = "Connecting to server..."

        End If


        If PerplexProgressBar1.Value = 50 Then
            PerplexLabel3.Text = "Connected. Looking for updates..."
        End If
        If PerplexProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            PerplexProgressBar1.Visible = False
            PerplexLabel3.Text = "Important updates are available on server."
            PerplexLabel1.Text = "Please download the updates to run the program now."
            PerplexButton2.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PerplexButton2.Click
        PerplexButton2.Visible = False
        PerplexProgressBar1.Visible = True
        Timer2.Start()
        PerplexProgressBar1.Value = PerplexProgressBar1.Minimum
        PerplexLabel1.Text = "Program will download the updates from server."
        PerplexLabel3.Text = "Downloading updates from server..."
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        PerplexProgressBar1.Increment(1)
        If PerplexProgressBar1.Value = 40 Then
            PerplexLabel3.Text = "Please wait... Program is updating..."
        End If
        If PerplexProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
            Timer2.Stop()
            PerplexProgressBar1.Visible = False
            PerplexLabel3.Text = "All updates have been downloaded right now."
            PerplexLabel1.Text = "Program has been successfully updated, run it!"
            PerplexButton3.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PerplexButton3.Click
        Me.Close()
        main.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub updater_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        Me.Opacity = 0
        main.Enabled = True
        main.Opacity = 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub updater_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        main.Show()
        main.Enabled = False
        main.Opacity = 0.9
    End Sub

    Private Function main() As Object
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: What seems to be the error?

Comment: Once again, please *state the specific problem you're having*, and *ask a specific question about that problem*. "Can someone correct errors in code?" is not an answerable question. You know what the errors are, because if you didn't you wouldn't know you had any. You have the error message right in front of you, so there's no reason not to include it in your question. Expecting us to try and figure out what question you're asking is simply unreasonable. **You** are asking **us** to *help you for free*. The least you can do is give us the information you already have to make it easier.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that the problem is within the last five or six lines of code. Any takers?

Comment: One Person wrote there are errors, but i don't know what. (i'm new in VB) -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344840/visual-basic-what-happened?noredirect=1#comment32181084_21344840 - "Since your program threw an exception, yes, there are errors."

Comment: But you have information about **the exception it threw**, don't you? You have tried to run the program? What **specific error** did you have? What **specific exception** was raised? You *really need to edit your question* to improve it. (What happens when you keep posting questions here that get downvoted or closed is that your account gets banned from posting any new questions. So if you leave it in bad condition and it keeps getting negative votes, you may not be able to ask more questions here when you have problems and need help.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Remove this line of code...It should run fine...

```
Private Function main() As Object
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function
```